# How many JSON files can AWS Athena query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Given an AWS S3 bucket containing 10 million JSON files of roughly 2kB.
What is a reasonable time for an AWS Athena query counting the frequency of some field values to be executed?

The question in not very detailed, but I'm only looking for ballpark figures.
Can AWS Athena handles this amount of data in a reasonable time?

Comment: Even if Athena can handle a large number of files, it would be extremely slow to process them. I recommend that you do some testing and find your preferred tolerance for time vs number of files. Could you possibly combine the files together to make fewer, larger input files?

Comment: Would Amazon Glue be an efficient way to aggregate those files before feeding the result to Athena?

Comment: If you are continuously receiving files, you can use Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose to consolidate data into fewer, larger files as they arrive. I'm not familiar with AWS Glue, so not sure if you can use it to combine existing files. If the files are separated into partitions or directories, you could use Athena to query them and store a combined set of results in a new location. Or, use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to provide a list of all objects and then run a Python script on EC2 to loop through them and combine them.